# Line Art not showing through transparency, but showing on transparent objects

Tags: transparency, grease-pencil, lineart

This character head is all one object but I am having a problem when applying Grease Pencil Line Art Modifier to the head with glasses. The eyebrows and eye lashes are joined geometry cards, with texture based transparency, the edge of the eyebrow and eyelash cards is showing Line Art, I'm trying to make this goes away. However when geometry edges that are supposed to have Line Art pass through transparency, the line art does not show (The glasses frame and edge of eye) I would like this to show line art.

Trying to understand the principle, setting, or technical limitation at work, so that I can do something about it. I've been playing with Occlusion settings, Material Masks and Intersection settings, but I can't find examples online, of what how these settings interact. General settings are as shown [image][image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering Grease Pencil lines behind Glass](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261267/rendering-grease-pencil-lines-behind-glass)

Comment: In the end, the easiest solution for this was to buy a license for Pencil+. It did everything I needed and got this project moving again in about an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the *Modifiers* tab and then expand the *Occlusion* there you just have to select *Range* then select *Level Start* to `0` and *End* to a higher number.

If you have problems like too many outlines then just change source type to *Collection* or *Object* then apply the Grease Pencil to separate objects or collections separately.

To remove outlines from unwanted objects, just change source type to *Collection* and remove the unwanted object`s from the collection.